# XSLT Transform not indenting properly

Tags: c#, .net, xml, transform, xslt

Here is an XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:P="http://abc.com/Xyz.xsd" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt">
    <xsl:output method="html" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="Thing">
        <xsl:element name="div">
            <xsl:attribute name="class">
                <xsl:text>Field</xsl:text>
            </xsl:attribute>

            <xsl:element name="span">
                <xsl:attribute name="class">
                    <xsl:text>Label</xsl:text>
                </xsl:attribute>

                <xsl:value-of select="$displayName"/>
                <xsl:text>:</xsl:text>
            </xsl:element>
            <xsl:element name="span">
                <xsl:attribute name="class">
                    <xsl:text>Input</xsl:text>
                </xsl:attribute>
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Here is the output of the XSLT Transformation:

```
<div class="Field"><span class="Label">Name:</span><span class="Input"></span></div>
```

Here is how I'm doing the transformation:

```
XslCompiledTransform xslTransform = new XslCompiledTransform();

xslTransform.Load(xsltPath, new XsltSettings(true, true), new XmlUrlResolver());

using (FileStream outputStream = File.Create(outputPath))
{
    using (StringReader stringReader = new StringReader(xml))
    {
        using (XmlReader xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(stringReader))
        {
            xslTransform.Transform(xmlReader, outputStream);
        }
    }
}
```

Why is the format not indented? Later on in the output, some things are indented. Not sure why. I'm looking for a solution that will honor the format settings as specified in the XSLT. This code is used to write to any format (XML, HTML, text, etc.) so I don't want specific code that will only work with XML, for example. But if my XSLT has an output of XML and is set to indent, then that should be honored.

Comment: Well how you do run the transformation? Whether the `xsl:output` is honored depends on how you run the transformation, if you use http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms163431.aspx for instance when you write to a file then the `xsl:output` is honored. That is also the case when you write to a stream. If you write to an XmlWriter then the `xsl:output` is not honored, unless you create the writer with e.g. `XslCompiledTransform p = new XslCompiledTransform(); p.Load("sheet.xsl"); using (XmlWriter xw = XmlWriter.Create("result.html", p.OutputSettings)) { // call Transform here }`.

Comment: Thanks, I've added the details of how I'm doing the transform.

Comment: In order to do anything on your question, the XML document (as small as possible) must also be provided. Please.

Answer (score 7):

By default `XmlWriter` (which here is being used implicitly by `XslCompiledTransform`) does not indent your xml, and won't automatically use the settings speicifed in your xslt.

You can either explicitly supply settings to an `XmlWriter` that specify that the output can be indented, or the better approach is to have `XmlWriter` use the settings supplied by the xslt:

```
XslCompiledTransform xslTransform = new XslCompiledTransform();
xslTransform.Load(xsltPath, new XsltSettings(true, true), new XmlUrlResolver());

using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(outputPath, xslTransform.OutputSettings))
{
    using (StringReader stringReader = new StringReader(xml))
    {
        using (XmlReader xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(stringReader))
        {
            xslTransform.Transform(xmlReader, writer);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but where does the `XmlWriter` come into play here? I see you've declared it in the `using` statement but it isn't used elsewhere.

Comment: @Josh Ah, my bad - I've fixed this up now.  I'm not *entirely* sure that this will work as your output is html instead of xml, but its worth a try.

Comment: I can't use XmlWriter because I'm looking for a solution that will honor the format settings as specified in the XSLT. This code is used to write to any format (XML, HTML, text, etc.) so I don't want specific code that will only work with XML, for example. If my XSLT has an output of XML and is set to indent, then that should be honored.

Comment: @Josh Have you tried this?  I've just been looking over some code generation of mine that uses XSLT (i.e. outputs plain text) - it also uses `XmlWriter` and works perfectly.  I guess the `XmlWriter` is just used to write text nodes and never cares that the output isn't really xml.

Comment: I did try it - the output is the same (not indented, and then all of the sudden, indented, and then back to not indented again).

Answer (score 5):

This is pretty old, but I ran across it when I was experiencing what i believe to be the same issue and none of the answers helped me. I ended up getting the correct indentation on my transformed xml after adding the tag below to my xslt.

```
<xsl:strip-space elements="*" />
```

I guess there was some white space throwing things off. Just wanted to put it here in case someone else stumbles upon like I did.

Answer (score -3):

HTML does not require indentation, so why do you?

If you really need indentation, use the [XmlWriter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlwriter.aspx) and [XmlWriterSettings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlwritersettings.aspx) classes to write to the FileStream object.